# Change the default apache configuration to serve HTTPS on two ports?

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, https, apache2

I'm running apache2 on Devuan Beowulf (~= Debian Buster), with the default configuration. In that configuration, I have:

in `sites-available/default-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        # etc etc.
```

in `sites-available/default-000.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # etc etc.
```

and in `sites-available/default-000.conf`:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

How do I make it so that apache listens on port 80 for HTTP traffic and on ports 443 and, say, 1234,  for HTTPS connections?

Answer (score 2):

There are several tasks here:

1. Make sure the SSL module is loaded
2. Listen on another port for SSL - port 1234 specifically
3. Make sure the `default-ssl.conf` site is enabled (or whatever site conf you want to use for your HTTPS site)
4. Make the port-443 virtual host also be served for the second port - without simply copying that block of configuration

Here's how to do it (as root):

1. Invoke `a2enmod ssl` (yes, there is such a utility)
2. Add `Listen 1234` right below `Listen 443` in `ports.conf`
3. Invoke `a2ensite default-ssl`
4. Change `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` to `<VirtualHost _default_:443 _default_:1234>` in `default-ssl.conf`.

There's (at least) one problem with the above solution, though - somehow, magically, you can speak HTTP to the server on port 443.

**Note:** *Don't* insert `NameVirtualHost` lines; if you do, you'll get warnings saying:

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next 
release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:6
```